# Mybb shows all threads as today

Tags: multithreading, time, mybb

I don't known where is the problem but MyBB shows every thread last activity as today - 09:53PM. Just like on image[image: MyBB Error]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Problem was in theme. I changed theme and everything works.